# Find the number of equations having real roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If both $a$ and $b$ belong to the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ ,
>   then number of equations of the form $ ax^2+bx+1=0$ having real roots is

$a.)\ 10\\
\color{green}{b.)\ 7}\\
c.)\ 6\\
d.)\ 12\\ $

To solve this I had to make a table and check each of the $16$ cases.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
 a & b & b^2-4a\geq 0 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & \\ \hline
1 & 2 & \checkmark \\ \hline
1 & 3 & \checkmark \\ \hline
1 & 4 & \checkmark \\ \hline
2 & 1 & \\ \hline
2 & 2 & \\ \hline
2 & 3 & \checkmark \\ \hline
2 & 4 & \checkmark \\ \hline
3 & 1 &  \\ \hline
3 & 2 &  \\ \hline
3 & 3 &  \\ \hline
3 & 4 & \checkmark \\ \hline
4 & 1 & \\ \hline
4 & 2 & \\ \hline
4 & 3 & \\ \hline
4 & 4 & \checkmark \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

But I would like to know if there is any short method for it.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade, thanks.

Comment: Here's another approach, though not necessarily shorter method. Since $a$ is positive, you know that the parabola opens upward. The $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola is given by $\frac{-b}{2a}$. You just need to check if $f(\frac{-b}{2a}) > 0$ (where $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$) to conclude that for the given $a,b$ that $f$ has complex roots.

Comment: @Math newbie You mean 'the $x$-co-ordinate of the VERTEX of the parabola'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For real roots,

$b^2\ge{4a}$

Put $a=1$.

$b^2\ge4$

$b$ can be $\{2,3,4\}$.

Now put $a=2$

$b$ can take two values.

Put $a=3$, $b$ can take one value and finally put $a=4$. Here $b$ can take one value.

Hence there are $7$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ so there are $7$ such equations